# Error creating auth token for newly registered user in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, access-token

I'm working on a Django project where I'm trying to create an auth token for a newly registered user using Django Rest Framework. However, when running the register function, I run into the following error:

`ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: Test>": "Token.user" must be a "User" instance.`

Here is the register function where the error occurs:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def register(request):
    serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()

        user = User.objects.get(username=request.data['username'])
        user.hash_password(request.data['password'])
        user.save()

        token = Token.objects.create(user=user) # This is where the error occurs

        return Response({
            'token': token.key,
            'User': serializer.data
        }, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How can I fix this error and successfully create the authentication token for the newly registered user?

I have tried to register a new user using the register function in my Django Rest Framework view. I was expecting the user to register successfully (register in the database) and for an auth token to be generated associated with that user.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend replacing token.objects.create with the following logic in your RegisterView:

```
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from rest_framework import generics, status
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer
from .models import User
from .utils import Util

class RegisterView(generics.GenericAPIView):
    """
    Register a new user with email and password and send verification email (Student or Tutor)
    """

    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=user)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        user_data = serializer.data
        user = User.objects.get(email=user_data["email"])

        refresh_token = RefreshToken.for_user(user)
        token = str(refresh_token.access_token)

        relative_link = reverse("verify-email")
        current_site = get_current_site(request).domain
        abs_url = "http://" + current_site + relative_link + "?token=" + token

        email_body = "Hi {}! Use the link below to verify your email:\n{}".format(
            user.full_name, abs_url)
        data = {
            "to_email": user.email,
            "email_body": email_body,
            "email_subject": "Verify your email",
        }
        Util.send_email(data)
    return Response(user_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This logic allows you to create a user and sends an email for email verification. Ensure that you have the necessary imports and configurations set up in your Django project.

Answer (score 0):

The `ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: Test>": "Token.user" must be a "User" instance.` error usually means that the "user" object is not an instance of the model that Token.user field expects.

Your code seems correct, after `serializer.save()`, the return value is an instance of User model. However, `hash_password` in line `user.hash_password(request.data['password'])` is not a standard Django method for User model. Please ensure this method exists in your User model and returns a User instance, not a string or something else. Also, this method probably does the same job as `set_password` which is already part of the Django User model.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely caused by your `hash_password` method, check its return type and make sure it returns a User instance. Also no need to use a custom made hashing method as the built in method `set_password` provides the same functionality.

Example of how it would look like using `set_password`:

```
user.set_password(request.data["password"])
user.save()
```